# The King by MattyB

Tags: meaning, rap

[The King](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDMX5uLCPHU) by MattyB is a rap song by 11 year old MattyB.

When he first starts rapping he says:

> You're the new model
>
> I'm in my zone making foog gottle
>
> You wanna grow up and put up the bottle

What does the second phrase mean?

Comment: http://genius.com/Mattyb-the-king-lyrics looks like a better source for the lyrics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual line is

> I'm in the zone going **full throttle**

meaning all out, top speed.

"In the zone" is sports lingo for being in an altered state of consciousness resulting in peak performance.

Comment: How did you get full throttle? In his lyrics it says foog gottle

Comment: The lyric was obvious from listening to the song in your link.  What is the source for your lyrics? It sounds like someone just transcribed it (very) poorly.

Comment: Use the link I had in my question

Comment: That's just a fan-made video.  The lyrics in it aren't official.  There's no meaning to the phrase "foog goottle."  If you listen to the actual song instead of reading the lyrics, you'll hear it correctly.

Comment: What resource did you use then?

Comment: As I mentioned twice already, I listened to the video from your link.  I didn't find the lyric difficult to understand.  I suspect that the person who transcribed it for the video might not be a native speaker of English.

Comment: what lyric resource did you use to view the "correct" lyircs